# Keep the top rows from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

For a dataframe which has an n variables which provides the frequency what command I need in order to select the top 10 high frequent rows based on n.

An example of the structure of the dataframe is this (unfortunatelly I can't provide the real data as they are to many)

```
df <- data.frame(status = c("open", "close", "close", "open/close", "close"), 
                 stock = c("google", "amazon", "amazon", "yahoo", "amazon"), 
                 newspaper = c("times", "newyork", "london", "times", "times"))

# Count the number of occurance for each alluvial
df <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(stock, newspaper, status) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
```

Comment: Does this: `… %>% arrange(-n) %>% filter(1:10)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the original rows, I recommend you to use `add_count` instead

```
df %>% 
  add_count(status, stock, newspaper) %>% 
  slice_max(n, n = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you need?

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(status, stock, newspaper, sort = TRUE) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 10)
```

alternatively, as suggested by @camille below:

```r
df %>% 
  count(status, stock, newspaper) %>% 
  slice_max(n)
```

Comment: If you use `slice_max` instead of `slice_head`, you don't have to worry about sorting